# Role of base measure in exponential family

Tags: exponential-family

An exponential family distribution $p$ in the canonical form can be written as

$p(x|\theta) = h(x)\exp(\theta^\top T(x) - A(\theta))$

where $A(\theta)$ is the log partition function, $T(x)$ is the sufficient statistics, and $h(x)$ is the base measure (according to this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)). For simplicity, let us consider a one dimensional $x$.

What is the restriction of the form of $h(x)$ ? My intuition tells me that $h(x)$ cannot be arbitrary because otherwise we can set $T(x)=0$, and leave all the "work" to $h(x)$.

For example, I understand that a Student's t is not in the exponential family. Let $t(x)$ be the density of a t distribution. If we set $T(x)=0$ and $h(x) = t(x)$, then

$A(\theta) = \log \int h(x)\exp(\theta^\top 0) \,dx = \log 1 = 0$,

and $p(x|\theta) = h(x) = t(x)$ implying that the t is in the exponential family.

What did I miss here ?

Comment: I believe the point isn't whether any given measure is part of an exponential family, for just the reasons you've noted, but whether a *family* is an exponential family.

Comment: I do not understand. What do you mean by "measure" ? Do you mean $h(x)$ or $p(x|\theta)$ or something else ?

Comment: I meant probability measure, but I should have said distribution, i.e. I was talking about $p(x | \theta)$.

Comment: This Stanford machine learning video on youtube explains it in a very good way [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZTeva0WSTQ&t=928s)

Answer (score 5):

Since $p(x|\theta)$ must integrate to 1, $h(x)$ must be non-negative, but that's the only restriction (according to page 111 in [this book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111885750X.html)).

However, I think the question highlights a common confusion (at least one that I've had before). There isn't just one exponential family of distributions.  Rather, there are many such exponential *families* as mentioned in the Exponential family Wikipedia article:

> exponential families are in a sense very natural sets of distributions
>   to consider.

The choice of the functions $h$ and $T$ specify the exponential family (i.e. model) and the parameter vector $\theta$ corresponds to a particular member (i.e. distribution) in that family.

Indeed, if you choose a some fixed degrees of freedom for the t-distribution (let's say $\nu = 3$), you could as you say let $T(x) = 0$ and $h(x) = t(x|\nu=3)$ which, following the formula on from the Student's t-distribution Wikipedia article, should give
$$
 h(x) = \frac{1} {\sqrt{3\pi}\,\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})} \left(1+\frac{x^2}{3} \right)^{-2}\!.$$

However, this doesn't give you the *family* of t-distributions, i.e. the set of functions $\{t(\cdot|\nu) : \nu > 0\}$. With this base distribution, you could construct a more interesting exponential family of distributions by using more interesting sufficient statistics $T(x)$, but you would not be able to design $T$ such that parameters $\theta$ would correspond to the $\nu$ parameter of the t-distribution.

Comment: I'd also mention that, while we can "design" $T(x)$, it is defined by Fisher as "a statistic... with respect to... [$f(x; \theta$)] if no other statistic that can be calculated from the same sample provides any additional information as to the value of the parameter".  Since forcing the T distribution into the exponential family form requires us to set $T(x)$ = 0, and $A(\theta)$ = 0, you're saying that no data provides information about $\theta$.  In an exponential family parametrized by $\theta$, distributions from the family are unidentifiable.

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas: the answer explains that an (infinity of) exponential family(ies) can be built out of this choice of function $h(x)$, which essentially modifies the dominating measure from the Lebesgue measure $\text d\mu$ to the Student measure $h(x)~\text d\mu$. Each of these exponential families is associated with a specific $T(x)$ in the exponential part and none corresponds to the Student's $t$ family.

Answer (score 1):

The central restriction is that $h(x)$ cannot depend on the parameters $\theta$. Intuitively, the base measure is the distribution of $x$ when the exponential term is given no weight i.e. $\theta=0$.
As mentioned in a comment to your question, this is related to the distinction between a family of distributions being an exponential family in itself vs. any single distribution being the member of *some* family.