# How to determine sample space, $\sigma$-algebra and probability measure from the exponential family?

Tags: exponential-family, sigma-algebra

The sample space of *binomial distribution* is the set $\{0,1\}$ and its $\sigma$-algebra is the power set of $\{0,1\}$ while the sample space of *normal distribution* is $\mathbb R$ and its $\sigma$-algebra is the Lebesgue measurable set. In these cases, the **probability measure** of *binomial distribution* is of the form of exponential family while the **radon-nikodym derivative of the probability measure** (i.e. pdf) of *normal distribution* is of the form of exponential family. Their natures are so different and why do people even call it a *family*?

My questions are:

1. How do we determine if exponential family gives us the probability measure or the probability density function?
2. How can we determine the sample space, $\sigma$-algebra and its probability measure from an exponential family?

Any help are welcome.

Comment: The sample space of a Binomial $\mathcal B(n,p)$ is $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some elements of answer:

- The pmf for a distribution with a countable sample space is its [density wrt to the counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function#Measure_theoretic_formulation).
- Exponential families are made of families of parametric distributions whose density wrt to a [given dominating measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) $\text d\lambda(x)$ write as $f_\theta(x)=\exp\{R(\theta)^\text{T}S(x)-\psi(\theta)\}$, where $\psi(\theta)$ is the log-normalising constant.$^1$ The Binomial and the Normal distributions belong to different exponential families.$^2$
- the sample space, $\mathfrak X$, its σ-algebra $\mathfrak B(\mathfrak X)$ and the dominating measure $\text d\lambda(x)$ are components of the definition of a given exponential family, just as much as the functions $R(\cdot)$ and $S(\cdot)$ above. If they are not provided, the associated exponential family is not defined.$^3$

---

$^1$I purposedly did not include the traditional $h(x)$ in the representation of $f_\theta(x)$, i.e., $f_\theta(x)=h(x)\exp\{R(\theta)^\text{T}S(x)-\psi(\theta)\}$ to stress the fact that $h(\cdot)$ can as well be part of the dominating measure. Changing $h(\cdot)$ thus amounts to [changing the dominating measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149814/role-of-base-measure-in-exponential-family?rq=1).

$^2$In particular, the Binomial distribution is absolutely continuous wrt the counting measure on $\mathfrak X=\mathbb N$ and the Normal distribution is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$

$^3$In other words, a probability distribution does not exist independently of its dominating measure, which itself does not exist independently of its σ-algebra $\mathfrak B(\mathfrak X)$, which itself requires a sample space $\mathfrak X$

Comment: I understand what a measure and a probability measure are, but a 'dominating' measure is new to me. What is it?

Comment: If you invoke the [Radon-Nykodim theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), you are using dominating measures.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It led me to this definition: ["*A measure $\mu$ on Borel subsets of the real line is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ if for every measurable set $A$, $\lambda (A) = 0 \implies \mu (A) = 0$. This is written $\mu << \lambda$. We say $\mu$ is dominated by $\lambda$.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures)

Comment: Is there any relation between the 3rd bullet point and the Pitman-Koopman-Darmois theorem besides the superficial analogy? In the first case, we require to specify the _domain_ to make the definition of a distribution meaningful. In the second case, having a fixed _support_ is one of the theorem's assumptions.

Comment: Except for the fact that the PKD theorem is about exponential families, I do not see the relation. From its definition, an exponential family distribution necessarily has a sample space that does not vary with the associated parameter.

Comment: Thank you from your clarification. The traditional $h(x)$ bothered me a lot.